# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

....trim(b);if(a.JSON&&a.JSON.parse)return a.JSON.parse(b);if(n.test(b.replace(o,"@...

jquery-....min.js (line 2, col 11012)

My code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cls_list_img3').live('click',function(){
            $('footer').after('<div class="error_bg" id="info_message" style="top: 0px; display: block;background:gold"><div class="center_auto"><div class="info_message_text message_area" style="color:black" id="msg_pin">Please Wait....</div><div onclick="return closeNotification()" class="info_close_btn button_area"></div><div class="clearboth"></div></div><div class="info_more_descrption"></div></div>');

             var imgsrc = $(this).attr('rel');
//alert(imgsrc);
            var img = imgsrc.replace('&', '*');
            var img1 = img.replace('&', '*');
            var img2 = img1.replace('&', '*');
            var img3 = img2.replace('&', '*');
            var img4 = img3.replace('&', '*');
             var title = encodeURIComponent($.trim($("#title").val().toString()));
             var body = $(this).children('.body').val();
             var rss_title = $(this).children('.title').val();
             var category = $(this).children('.category').val();
             var rss_link = $(this).children('.rss_link').val();
              var data = "imgsrc=" + img4 + "&source="+rss_link+"&title=" + rss_title+"&des="+body+"&rss_title="+rss_title+"&category="+category;
            // alert(body);
             //alert(rss_title);
               $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>share/pinuploudOneclick",
                                      dataType: 'json',
                                    // async: true,
                                     data: data,
                                     success: function(data)
                {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                    //alert(data);
                    alert(obj.message);
                       if(obj.message == 'error'){
                           $('#msg_pin').html('You already uploaded this Pin');
                $('#info_message').css('background','lightpink');

                           }else{
                    $('#msg_pin').html('Pin uploaded successfully');
                    $('#info_message').css('background','lightgreen');
                }
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        $('#info_message').remove();
                         }, 3000);
                   // $('#fadeimgoverlay').removeClass('fadeimgoverlay_bg');
                   // $('#fadeimgloading').hide();
                    //$('.event-containernarrow').html(data);
                   // $('.main_container').css('display', 'none');
                    //$('.bd_detail').html(data);
                    //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
                },
                dataType: "html"
            });







            })
        });
```

Comment: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` - `data` is already parsed

Comment: yes ... but a SyntaxError message display at console .

Comment: Propably because of the double parse as T.J. Crowser has explained in his answer

Answer (score 3):

jQuery parses the JSON for you before calling `success` because you've specified `dataType: 'json'`. (If you hadn't, and the server replied with the correct `Content-Type`, it would have done it anyway.) So you can just use `data` directly, you don't want to call `JSON.parse` on it.

So change your `success` function from

```
success: function(data)
{
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // Don't need this!
    alert(obj.message);
    // ...
```

to

```
success: function(obj)                // Just use this directly
{
    alert(obj.message);
    // ...
```

From the documentation:

> `success`
>
> Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, **formatted according to the `dataType` parameter or the `dataFilter` callback function**, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

*(My emphasis)*

By doing it *again*, you end up calling `toString` on `data`, which probably results in either `"[object Object]"` (if the top level thing is an object) or something else unparseable (if the top level thing is an array, as `Array#toString` calls `Array#join`). That's why you get the error.